# What is the need for the SIP RE-INVITE with regards to ICE?

Tags: p2p, sip, voip, nat, ice

I understand many of the fine details of NAT hole punching, ICE, and SIP VOIP calls. I've answered quite a few questions on SO on these topics.  Now I have a question.

I am trying to understand the need for the RE-INVITE message that is documented for SIP+ICE after the call is already established.

Assume a topology of VOIP devices that signal over SIP and using ICE (with STUN/TURN) for establishing media connectivity. After the ICE connectivity checks are performed, both endpoints should have ascertained the best address candidate pairings (IP,port) and should be ready to stream media in both directions.

But my experience with SIP and plenty of documentation suggests that after the callee sends a 200 OK message to indicate he's in the answered state, the caller is to expected send a RE-INVITE with an SDP containing the specific address candidate selected by the connectivity checks.

Some links that describe the RE-INVITE with ICE are [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd922358%28v=office.12%29.aspx) and [here](http://voiptraversal.com/ice_methodology.htm) (step 8).  Rosenberg's [tutorial](http://www.jdrosen.net/papers/ice-basic-tutorial.pdf) (page 30) discusses that the RE-INVITE "ensures that middleboxes have the correct media address".  I'm not sure why that's important.

Upon receiving a RE-INVITE, is the callee expected to reconfigure his ICE stack to switch sockets or addresses based on the new SDP received?  Or is the RE-INVITE just a protocol formality to formally acknowledge the call has been established?  If the RE-INVITE step was skipped and both sides started streaming media, what could go wrong?

The reason why I ask is because I am exploring using ICE over a signaling service that is not SIP. I'm trying to figure out if the RE-INVITE needs to be emulated.

Comment: What the down voter care to explain why he didn't like this question?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One example of middlebox, which may be interested in the result of the ICE negotiation is a bandwidth manager.

Imagine an enterprise deployment, with endpoints inside the corporate firewall and others roaming around on the Internet, or behind private home firewalls. The deployment also includes a publicly accessible TURN server. Then let's imagine an endpoint inside the corporate firewall making a call. If the destination happens to be reachable on the same network, the call will go host to host and the TURN server will not be used (i.e. bindings will be de-allocated). This is a local network, and no bandwidth limitation needs to be imposed. On the other hand, if the call goes out to a roaming endpoint, then the TURN server will get involved, and data will flow through the corporate firewall, through what probably is a limited bandwidth uplink. We can very well imagine some policy that would want to limit the call's bandwidth. One way of doing it, is for the bandwidth manager to remain in the signaling path (using SIP record-routes) and look into the SDP of any INVITE going through, re-writing bandwidth values depending on media addresses.

I believe the general intention was, that legacy equipment of that type, which is not ICE aware, should keep working in a mixed environment introducing ICE endpoints. To keep this backwards compatibility, ICE should only introduce new processing (STUN checks, etc), but from the point of view of non-ICE-aware elements, it should not remove any existing rules (re-INVITEs are still needed to change the destination of a media stream).

Comment: Thanks Baint.  Best answer I've heard so far.

Answer (score 4):

In Rosenberg's tutorial I believe the re-INVITE is sent because the sockets chosen by ICE are different from those in the media and connection (m/c-lines) lines of the original SDP AND in order for any network elements that are in between the two user agents to be informed of the actual sockets that will be used RTP a re-INVITE is sent with the ICE selected socket(s) in the media and connection lines of the SDP.

If the ICE selected sockets were the same as the ones in the original INVITE request's SDP m/c lines then there would be no need for the re-INVITE request. Or if you know there are no "middleboxes" that need to be informed of the changes to the RTP sockets then there would also be no need to send the re-INVITE.

Comment: Are you simply quoting the stuff directly from the document I linked in my question without actually expanding on it?  :)  What is the "m/c" line anyway?  What is a "middlebox" in this context?  The original INVITE will have several address candidates (host, srflx,relay) in the SDP for each media socket.  The subsequent RE-INVITE will have the one selected by ICE for each media type.  But the ICE stack of the non-controlling agent (callee) already negotiated this (from what I understand). What is the callee supposed to do with the RE-INVITE other than just ack it with another 200 OK?

Comment: I would recommend reading my answer again, slowly. The m/c lines are the media and connection lines in the SDP, as I've attempted to point out. Middleboxes are most likely network elements between the ends of the call that also need to pass the RTP. The purpose of the re-INVITE is not for an ICE re-negotiation.

Comment: I do appreciate the answer and the effort. The premise of  my question was essentially, "**why** is the re-invite necessary"? I think you answered **what** the SIP RE-INVITE is for, but your answer could have been improved by answering **why** it is needed.